# Need to convert a column or data to 0 or 1 in R

Tags: r

I am doing an assignment with the built-in "SWISS" dataset, and where the value is greater than 50 I need to create a binary variable taking 1

I have a feeling that I might have to use the subset command, but I am lost as how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

using [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

```
swiss %>% 
   mutate(aggGreaterThan50 = (Agriculture > 50) * 1)
```

Comment: I would argue that `as.numeric(Agriculture > 50)` is stylistically preferable (I find the `*1/+0` tricks for converting to numeric to be a little *too* tricky/terse ...